# finding the first element that is needed

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this array

```
Array
(
    [name] => Step1 is here
    [standard] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 85,99
            [product_name] => Step1 is here
            [product_price] => 976.0000
            [product_description] => :something 
            [product_image] => http://someurl.com/shop_pos/image/data/13D.png
        )

    [professional] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 61
            [product_name] => Step1 is here
            [product_price] => 289.0000
            [product_description] => somethingothere 
            [product_image] => http://someurl.com/shop_pos/image/data/13B.png
        )
    [premium] => Array
        (
            [product_id] => 677
            [product_name] => Step1 is here
            [product_price] => 289.0000
            [product_description] => somethingothere 
            [product_image] => http://someurl.com/shop_pos/image/data/13A.png
        )

)
```

Is there an easy of referencing in the proper order that i need. SO the order i need is standard, professional, premium.. so if one is not present can I do to the other like this

```
 if (!isset($my_array['standard'])) {
 $use_me = $my_array['standard']
}elseif(!isset($my_array['professional'])) {
 $use_me = $my_array['professional']
}elseif(!isset($my_array['professional'])) {
    $use_me = $my_array['premium']}
}
```

i have the above code that i think may work but is there a better way

Comment: I don't understand what that could should be doing. You're using the value if it's *not* set?

Comment: basically i want a better way of finding which one to use in a proper order. SOme maybe set and some might not

Comment: the value should be professional

Comment: and if professional is not set then use premium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
foreach (array('standard', 'professional', 'premium') as $name) {
    if (isset($my_array[$name])) {
        $use_me = $my_array[$name];
        break;
    }
}
```

or a little more structured:

```
function selectPlan($array) {
    foreach (array('standard', 'professional', 'premium') as $name) {
        if (isset($array[$name])) return $array[$name];
    }
}

$use_me = selectPlan($my_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

That should do it:

```
$keys = array_slice(array_keys($my_array), 1, 1);
$use_me = $my_array[$keys[0]];
```

In short:

1. Get the array keys (name, standard, professional, premium). (`array_keys`)
2. Get the second key (bypassing `name`, so it returns `standard` or whatever the second key is). (`array_slice`)
3. Reference `$my_array` using that key and store it in `$use_me`.

Comment: @Tamer: See updated answer. Also, updated code to make it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it the way you have presented in your code. However, your if statement logic is not correct. Your code should be like this:

```
if (isset($my_array['standard'])) {
    $use_me = $my_array['standard'];
} elseif(isset($my_array['professional'])) {
    $use_me = $my_array['professional'];
} elseif(isset($my_array['premium'])) {
    $use_me = $my_array['premium'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, and if the order of the keys is not guaranteed to be exactly like the one in the example, you can do something like:

```
// initialization
$use_me = 'default value';

// go through each package
foreach (array('standard', 'professional', 'premium') as $package) {
    // when we find a package that does exist
    if (isset($my_array[$package])) {
        // mark it as found and exit the loop
        $use_me = $package;
        break;
    }
}
```

This will go through all the packages and set the `$use_me` variable to the first found value. If no value is found, it sets it to a default value.

Answer (score 1):

try with **[array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)**

```
foreach($input as $k=>$v) {

if (array_key_exists('standard', $k)) {
$output [$k] = $k;
}
if (array_key_exists('professional', $k)) {
$output [$k] = $k;
}
if (array_key_exists('premium', $k)) {
$output [$k] = $k;
}
```

}

or u can go through **[array-intersect-key](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)**